# Why is AutoMapper accessing properties when I tell it not to?

Tags: c#, automapper

I've setup a simple test case; here are my types:

```
public class FullCompanyInfo {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Foo { get; set; }
    public string Bar { get; set; }
    public FullCompanyInfo Parent { get; set; }
}
public class CompanyInChainDTO
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public CompanyInChainDTO Parent { get; set; }
}
```

And here is my mapping config:

```
cfg.CreateMap<FullCompanyInfo, CompanyInChainDTO>()
    .ForMember(dto => dto.Parent, opt =>
    {
        // Stop recursive parent mapping when name is 33
        opt.Condition(comp => {
            return comp.Name != "33";
        });
    });
```

Now I setup the original object graph to map, map it, and show the JSON result:

```
FullCompanyInfo comp = new FullCompanyInfo
{ Id = 1, Name = "11", Foo = "Foo1", Bar = "Bar1", Parent = new FullCompanyInfo
    { Id = 2, Name = "22", Foo = "Foo2", Bar = "Bar2", Parent = new FullCompanyInfo
        { Id = 3, Name = "33", Foo = "Foo3", Bar = "Bar3", Parent = new FullCompanyInfo {
            Id = 4, Name = "44", Foo = "Foo4", Bar = "Bar4", Parent = null }
        }
    }
};

CompanyInChainDTO compChain = _mapper.Map<CompanyInChainDTO>(comp);
var jsonResult = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(compChain);
```

And the result is:

```
{
  "Id": 1,
  "Name": "11",
  "Parent": {
    "Id": 2,
    "Name": "22",
    "Parent": {
      "Id": 3,
      "Name": "33",
      "Parent": null
    }
  }
}
```

So far it seems fine, the mapping of `Parent` stopped when `Name` was 33.  However, when I debug the `opt.Condition` lambda at `return comp.Name != "33";`, I find that AutoMapper is passing in the original `FullCompanyInfo` objects in this order:

```
Id: 44
Id: 33
Id: 22
Id: 11
```

So it is accessing all 4 of the objects, even though `44` never makes it into the final mapping!  It's as if Automapper is fully exploring the object graph and then removing properties if my `Condition` returns false.  Why would it not call the lambda for `11` first, and so on, and only load the `FullCompanyInfo` sub-object if it's told to map that member?

The trouble is that in a context where these aren't just in-memory entities, but entities that take time and resources to access, AutoMapper is going to access stuff it doesn't need to instead of just stopping when `Condition` tells it not to map the referenced entity.

Answer (score 2):

3 letters: `Pre`.

Can't believe I wasted a bunch of time on this; I needed to use `opt.PreCondition(...)` instead.  It actually stops accessing the source member when you tell it not to.

Comment: Yes :) See [this](http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Conditional-mapping.html#preconditions).